# How do i add/remove item from the select on rails nested model form using coffee

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, simple-form

Here is my form

[image]

There are 8 items in select,

I want to remove the item from select if its already used on top. I shouldn't be able to do the following:

[image]

If user have already selected an item above, on the following select option the item shouldn't be there.

Same thing in opposite when clicking remove, If a form is removed the new form should have the item.

Here is my coffee code

```
ready = ->
  $('#FuelmodelBody').on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
    $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
    $(this).closest('.row').hide()
    event.preventDefault()

  $('#FuelmodelBody').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault()

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

Comment: suyesh, there is a gem called cocoon that makes this easy

Comment: How do i validate that in my model?

Comment: How do you mean validate?

Comment: Validate that there is no duplications? User should't be able to submit if they have chosen multiple "Item 1" in the same form.

Comment: Like above i have chosen "87 RFG" 2 times in the select.

Comment: I guess you can use `validate_uniqueness_of` validator.